# ViewModel unit testing, System.Threading.Task and ContinuteWith

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, unit-testing

I am using `System.Threading.Tasks` to execute my long running service calls and using `ContinueWith` to update my `ViewModel`. To unit test this view model updation after task excecution I have exposed the `Task` returned by `ContinueWith` call as a `readonly` property so that unit tests can call `Wait()` on the task and go on to test the `ViewModel` updation.

Is this the only way to do it, is there any other cleaner option ? I am a but worried that the task exposes too many methods (like `Dispose`, `Start`) which is not intended to be exposed.

Comment: I am not proficient in TPL, but can't you provide your own threading model? In that case, your unit test could override the default model and take full control, be it running on the same thread or whatever.

Comment: How is your service retrieved? If you have some kind of Dependency Injection or a factory method you could just return a Mock Service that delivers some fake results.
This way you won't have to expose your internal knowledge of the specific task to the outside world.

Comment: I am already mocking the service on my unit tests, currently I am trying to test if the view model reacts correctly after the service returns the values. Setting the right properties, rising property changed notification etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing it old school style. Exposed a method `WaitOnLoadTask()` that calls `Task.Wait()` instead of exposing the whole `Task` as a property.